# Mixing JSON data and image content in a single HTTP response

Tags: spring, http, servlets

Is it possible to include multiple response types in a single HTTP response? For example, JSON data as well as an image.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You probably wouldn't use it in a browser intended app though. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey It is not possible to set multiple `MIME TYPE` to `HTTPResponse`. But what you can do is, you can set the content type as `application/json`. And using `json` you can send the image using BASEEncoder.

```
public static String encodeToString(BufferedImage image, String type) {
    String imageString = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, type, bos);
        byte[] imageBytes = bos.toByteArray();

        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        imageString = encoder.encode(imageBytes);

        bos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return imageString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  I think one generally would send the URL of image in json, and use javascript to update the "src" attribute of "img" element