# Set Headers for Both JSON and Image at the Same Time in the Same Endpoint

Tags: angularjs, spring, microservices

I'm trying to return a BadgeResponseDTO in my controller which has a string vetId, string badgeDate, string badgeTitle, and Resource resource, but Resource resource needs to be returned with header "MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE" while the other attributes (vetId, badgeDate, and badgeTitle) need to be returned with header "MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE". Would there be a way to implement both headers in my controller? If not, what would be the best alternative?

DTO I want to return back

```
package com.petclinic.bffapigateway.dtos.Vets;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BadgeResponseDTO {
    private String vetId;
    private String badgeDate;
    private BadgeTitle badgeTitle;
    private Resource resource;
}
```

Enum used in BadgeResponseDTO

```
package com.petclinic.bffapigateway.dtos.Vets;

public enum BadgeTitle {
    VALUED,
    MUCH_APPRECIATED,
    HIGHLY_RESPECTED
}
```

VetsServiceClient class

```
public Mono<BadgeResponseDTO> getBadgeByVetId(String vetId){
        return webClientBuilder.build()
                .get()
                .uri(vetsServiceUrl + "/" + vetId+ "/badge")
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatusCode::is4xxClientError, error->{
                    HttpStatusCode statusCode = error.statusCode();
                    if(statusCode.equals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND))
                        return Mono.error(new NotFoundException("vetId not found: "+vetId));
                    return Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException("Something went wrong"));
                })
                .onStatus(HttpStatusCode::is5xxServerError, error->
                        Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException("Something went wrong"))
                )
                .bodyToMono(BadgeResponseDTO.class);
    }
```

```
package com.petclinic.vet.servicelayer.badges;

import com.petclinic.vet.dataaccesslayer.badges.BadgeRepository;
import com.petclinic.vet.dataaccesslayer.badges.BadgeTitle;
import com.petclinic.vet.dataaccesslayer.ratings.RatingRepository;
import com.petclinic.vet.exceptions.InvalidInputException;
import com.petclinic.vet.exceptions.NotFoundException;
import com.petclinic.vet.util.EntityDtoUtil;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.StreamUtils;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.io.IOException;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BadgeServiceImpl implements BadgeService{
    private final BadgeRepository badgeRepository;
    private final RatingRepository ratingRepository;

    @Override
    public Mono<BadgeResponseDTO> getBadgeByVetId(String vetId) {
        return badgeRepository.findByVetId(vetId)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new NotFoundException("vetId not found: " + vetId)))
                .flatMap(badge -> {
                    return ratingRepository.countAllByVetId(vetId)
                            .flatMap(count -> {
                                if (count == 0) {
                                    return Mono.just(0.0);
                                } else {
                                    return ratingRepository.findAllByVetId(vetId)
                                            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new NotFoundException("vetId is Not Found" + vetId)))
                                            .map(EntityDtoUtil::toDTO)
                                            .reduce(0.0, (acc, rating) -> acc + rating.getRateScore())
                                            .map(sum -> sum / count);
                                }
                            })
                            .flatMap(avgRating -> {
                                if (avgRating <= 2.0) {
                                    return loadBadgeImage("images/empty_food_bowl.png")
                                            .map(imageData -> {
                                                badge.setData(imageData);
                                                badge.setBadgeTitle(BadgeTitle.VALUED);
                                                return badge;
                                            });
                                } else if (avgRating <= 4.0) {
                                    return loadBadgeImage("images/half-full_food_bowl.png")
                                            .map(imageData -> {
                                                badge.setData(imageData);
                                                badge.setBadgeTitle(BadgeTitle.MUCH_APPRECIATED);
                                                return badge;
                                            });
                                } else if (avgRating <= 5.0) {
                                    return loadBadgeImage("images/full_food_bowl.png")
                                            .map(imageData -> {
                                                badge.setData(imageData);
                                                badge.setBadgeTitle(BadgeTitle.HIGHLY_RESPECTED);
                                                return badge;
                                            });
                                } else {
                                    return Mono.just(badge);
                                }
                            });
                })
                .map(EntityDtoUtil::toBadgeResponseDTO);
    }

    private Mono<byte[]> loadBadgeImage(String imagePath) {
        try {
            ClassPathResource cpr = new ClassPathResource(imagePath);
            return Mono.just(StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(cpr.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException io) {
            return Mono.error(new InvalidInputException("Picture does not exist: " + io.getMessage()));
        }
    }
}
```

BFFApiGatewayController class

```
@GetMapping("{vetId}/badge")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<BadgeResponseDTO>> getBadgeByVetId(@PathVariable String vetId){
        return badgeService.getBadgeByVetId(vetId)
                .map(r->ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(r))
                .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.badRequest().build());
    }
```

Methods in my vet-details.controller.js

```
$http.get('api/gateway/vets/'+$stateParams.vetId+'/badge').then(function(resp){
            self.badge=resp.data;
            console.log(resp.data)
        })
        self.init = function (){
            $http.get('api/gateway/vets/' + $stateParams.vetId + '/badge').then(function (resp) {
                self.badge= resp.data;
                console.log(resp.data)
            });
        }
```

vet-details.template.html

```
<div class="parent">
                    <img alt="Badge preview" src="data:image/*;base64, {{$ctrl.badge.resource}}" width="150" height="150" class="image1">
                </div>
```

I tried to change the header depending on the type of my Resource inside my BadgeResponseDTO, but it didn't work. I was expecting the header to vary between "MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE" for data types that can be returned in json format and "MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE" for my Resource in my dto since it's an image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mixing JSON data and image content in a single HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371236/mixing-json-data-and-image-content-in-a-single-http-response)

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!